# Как сделать разрыв у text в API Recharts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recharts

Есть график за год и его text где отображается в виде чисел + млн, выглядит читабельно, все хорошо.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но есть график за 3 года
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И это выглядит ужасно. По документации у меня есть функция CustomizedLabel.
В value попадает список данных в виде чисел.

```
  const CustomizedLabel = ({ x, y, value }) => {
    return (
      <text x={x} y={y} dy={-10} fill="#fff" fontSize={14}>
        {value.toString().slice(0, 3) + ' млн'}
      </text>
    );
  };
```

Соответственно функция попадает в Line

```
<Line type="linear" dataKey="revenue" stroke="#fff" label={<CustomizedLabel />}/>
```

Я не нашел в документации как сделать разрыв. Мне нельзя сокращать месяца и уменьшать шрифт, точки должны идти за каждый месяц а его текст в виде числа + млн должен идти с разрывом 7 шагов, чтобы все было читабельно.

Comment: 7 шагов - показыать каждый 7 месяц?

Comment: Я бы хотел показывать text не по порядку как в графике за 3 года, а через 2, чтобы просто было читабельно, чтобы не приоепал текст друг к другу. Не обязательно делать сильный разрыв.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавим в компонент новые параметры: `step` - шаг вывода значений и `zeroInclude` - показывать первый элемент или нет.

```
<Line 
  type="linear" 
  dataKey="revenue" 
  stroke="#fff" 
  label={<CustomizedLabel step={3} zeroInclude={true} />}
/>
```

и модифицируем компонент кастомизации вывода под наши потребности:

```
const CustomizedLabel: FunctionComponent<any> = (props: any) => {
  const { x, y, value, index, step, zeroInclude } = props;
  let flag = false;
  // Рассчитываем флаг
  if (zeroInclude && index === 0) {
    flag = true;
  } else {
    flag = (index + 1) % step === 0;
  }
  // Если флаг true выводим
  return (
    <text x={x} y={y}  dy={-10} fill="#fff" fontSize={14}>
      {flag ? value.toString().slice(0, 3) + ' млн' : null}
    </text>
  );
};
```

В компонент в props приходит индекс элемента, поэтому можно смело его использовать для определения номера.
В компоненте рассчитываем флаг отображения текста.

Как и обычный компонент реакта, вы можете дополнять функционал как хотите.

Comment: Спасибо большое !